# XmlSlurper to parse XML and get value of inside elements using Groovy

Tags: java, xml, parsing, groovy, xmlslurper

I am trying to parse the below XML:

```
    <body>
      <section id="5f884f20-6638-461f-a3f5-3d237341c048" outputclass="definition_and_scope">
        <title>Definition and Scope</title>
        <p>A work that is modified for a purpose, use, or medium other than that for which it was originally intended.</p>
        <p>This relationship applies to changes in form or to works completely rewritten in the same form.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="a7cf019f-dc82-46e2-b5ae-2e947d3c2509" outputclass="popup:ready_reference">
        <title>Element Reference</title>
        <div id="8472e205-3a32-40e3-a7ea-8bd7dbd43715" outputclass="iri">
          <p id="e6ddf17a-6b4b-4de3-886e-a315d88545ea" outputclass="title">
            <b>IRI</b>
          </p>
          <p id="c69f6279-27a3-4cd8-84a6-bb2c5a7b0424">
            <xref format="html" href="http://rdaregistry.info/Elements/w/P10142" scope="external">http://rdaregistry.info/Elements/w/P10142</xref>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="3e979983-cbac-4982-84c7-57ae9756e2bb" outputclass="domain">
          <p id="9815dbdf-7483-4dcf-8166-7ea50138b3e5" outputclass="title">
            <b>Domain</b>
          </p>
          <p id="328a1035-1eaf-4c4b-aead-d604586b3f64">
            <xref keyref="rdacC10001/ala-c3e1fff8-0a79-35c6-bee1-39b6b4c9ed35">Work</xref>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="13163eda-dcfd-48d9-aea4-cc8abef2f675" outputclass="range">
          <p id="d07d4e37-dff1-4561-baab-f8f557d99662" outputclass="title">
            <b>Range</b>
          </p>
          <p id="3873a6ab-5f73-47e2-9daa-441169e66c36">
            <xref keyref="rdacC10001/ala-c3e1fff8-0a79-35c6-bee1-39b6b4c9ed35">Work</xref>
          </p>
        </div>
    </section>
   </body>
```

I want to extract the values of all the p tags inside of section & section/div and append that value to a stringbuilder.

Here is my code:

```
def docText = new StringBuilder();
def bodyObject = doc.topic.body.toXmlString(true) //I have only pasted a part of my XML in this question. My XML starts with a doc/topic/body etc
def parseBodyObject = new XmlSlurper().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(bodyObject)));
def findAllSection = parseBodyObject.depthFirst().findAll{it.name()=='section'}

findAllSection.each {section->

      docText.append(" " +section.p)
      docText.append(" " +section.div.p + " ")

}
```

Output:
My docText looks like below:

```
A work that is modified for a purpose, use, or medium other than that for which it was originally intended.This relationship applies to changes in form or to works completely rewritten in the same form. IRIhttp://rdaregistry.info/Elements/w/P10142DomainWorkRangeWorkAlternate labelsUser tasksRecording methodsDublin Core TermsMARC 21 Bibliographic Recording an unstructured descriptionRecording a structured descriptionRecording an identifierRecording an IRI For the inverse of this element, see Work: adapted as work For broader elements, see Work: based on workFor narrower elements, see
```

I am stuck at adding a space between text. For eg. When it is going through section/div/p, it is adding all the p together without any spaces as below:

```
IRIhttp://rdaregistry.info/Elements/w/P10142DomainWorkRangeWorkAlternate
```

which should output as(expected output):

```
IRI http://rdaregistry.info/Elements/w/P10142 Domain Work
```

How should I get these values separated? Any help is appeciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this `depthFirst().findAll { it.name() == 'section'}` returns an array list which element is a combination of the inner text of p tags.

Let's define your sample XML as `xmlDoc`. Below is the snippet of code that works as expected:

```
def parseBodyObject = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlDoc)
def findAllPtags = parseBodyObject.children().depthFirst().findAll { 
   it.name() == 'p'
}
def docText = new StringBuilder()
findAllPtags.each { p ->
   docText.append("\n" + p)
}
```

You can replace `\n` by a space.